# Does anyone have idea how i can remove this shading distortion?

Tags: modeling

I more or less fixed other distortions by either Loop Subdivide or knife tool, but whit this mesh i have way more problems, simply cause i cant use Loop Subdivide to fix it...

Has anyone have a idea how i can make it less visible?(only outsisde, inside dosent matter.)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try checking the Auto Smooth option in the Normals panel of the Object Data tab in the Properties panel. (The option at the top of the tab with the 3 vertex triangle)

Comment: I disabled autosmooth and recalculated normals and it looks now better, what happens when i eventually export it to .dae and have all meshes except this one autosmoothed?